# Custom date format for only 1 index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to define a custom date format for only 1 index.

Actually, I have the `@timestamp` field in index A in the following format,

```
`25/Jul/2017:12:41:18 +0530`
```

And elasticsearch has **stored it as a string instead of datetime.**

My other indices in elasticsearch have the `@timestamp` field in the correct format i.e, `2017-07-25T15:46:37+05:30`.

So, I want to declare a custom format but for only 1 index, so that other indices should not be affected. Can I do this ? If yes, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a custom date format in the mapping of this specific index (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html):

I would start with this: `"format": "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"`